# Problem with PHP includes on case-sensitive file systems

Tags: php

I've built a PHP project in Windows, and as you know in Windows fun.php and Fun.php is same but not in Linux.
**Q1->** As my project will run in Linux How to solve this issue [error for file name] ?
**Q2->** I need to show an error if exact file name does not exist ! How to do so ?

Example

I have this 2 PHP file in `template.php` and `render.php`
Code of `render.php`

```
include 'Template.php';
```

I want to get an warning so i can fix this issue [which does not create problem in Windows, but in Linux]

Comment: Don't rely on case insensitivity in file names?

Comment: All these answers are fine, but in the time it took to ask this and implement one of them, you could have just fixed your file names.

Comment: To @Rafe's comment...it seems like a bad habit to haphazardly name files. If it were me (regardless of who made the mess), I'd clean it up. Fix the file names, and pass on the functions/workarounds to undo it, which will no doubt create a new set of caveats to post questions here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution #1: Use all lowercase.
Solution #2: Use the exact same case every time. Instead of trying to include "Template" when the file name is "template", just include the lowercase "template" in the first place. Most programming languages are case sensitive anyway, so it's best to get into the practice. While filename may be unique in this matter, for example, a variable in PHP must use the same case, so just apply the same principals to file names.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if I were in that situation, I'd write a wrapper around include:

```
function warned_include($file)
{
    if( defined( 'DEBUG_ENV' ) ) // define this somewhere else while in dev.
    {
        foreach( explode( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path() ) as $path )
        {
            // make sure the / is replaced with the OS native DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            $fullPath = str_replace($path .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file, '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            if( is_file( $fullPath ) )
            {
                $spl = new SplFileInfo( $fullPath );
                if( $spl->getPathname() != $fullPath )
                {
                    echo 'case sensitivity mismatch for ' . $spl->getPathname();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    include $file;
}
```

I've not had a chance to test it, but SplFileInfo gets the pathname from the OS, which means that it should have correct case sensitivity in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You have a 'shortcut' in windows where you call a file `Template` while it is actually calles `template`. If you just go trough your code and not allow that, you'd be fine?

- Make sure all your filenames are in one case, or use one standard (if you just have 'basic' pages, i'd go with all lowercase. But sometimes in bigger projects you'd have a standard that says classes go with a capital like ClassName.php)
- make sure your calls use that actual name.
- ...
- profit.

If for some reason you don't want that, you can always use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) for classes. Every class that is called will load that class if it can't find itself. this will obviously be not ideal for situations where you want to include stuff that is not in classes.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should replace all includes with require. Require throws fatal error if there is no such file exists (not in proper case too)

YOu might find this helpful. - http://clarityamidstchaos.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/how-to-perform-a-case-insensitive-file_exists-lookup-in-phplinux/

Comment: I also recommend cwallenpoole method. +1up

Comment: I like how you typed "YOu" on a question about case sensitive