# class_exists only works when the static class property is called

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working in a project where composer handles the autoloading.

I have a class :

```
namespace App\Foo;

use MyCLabs\Enum\Enum;

/**
 * @method static Bar MY_CONST()
 */
class BarFOO extends Enum
{
    const MY_CONST = 'my_const';
    ...
}
```

I have a basic class_exists checking (in reality it's dynamic so I cant't call the Bar::class directly) :

```
$strClass = '\App\Foo\BarFoo';
var_dump(class_exists($strClass));
```

That returns false while the class really exists.

However, when I do the following :

```
$strClass = '\App\Foo\BarFoo';

var_dump(class_exists($strClass)); // false
var_dump(class_exists(\App\Foo\BarFOO::class)); // true
var_dump(class_exists($strClass)); // true
```

Then the last var_dump returns true while it's exactly the same as the first !

Does anyone has a clue ?

**EDIT**

I edited my question as the answer was not guessable !
In fact my string value didn't match the original class name :

```
BarFoo // string value
BarFOO // Class name
```

So as the file system is case sensitive, my class file was not found.

But as soon as I used my class static property, the class was registered in the autoloader which is case insensitive !

So now I got to figure out how to retrieve the correct class name but this is another problem !

Thank you for your help and sorry not to have posted a complete question !

Comment: Not sure it'd make a difference (probably not), but string class names are always absolute, so the correct way to refer to the class is `'App\Foo\Bar'`, without the leading backslash.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, I figured it out, unfortunately, I missed the fact that my class name ended with many uppercases and the string variable didn't !

Comment: @deceze it works in both cases but I prefer your way indeed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with PHP includes on case-sensitive file systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475931/problem-with-php-includes-on-case-sensitive-file-systems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who ever ecounter the problem, pay attention to the case situation.

In my case (huhu) my class name ended with several uppercases (BarFOO) but my string class name was not (BarFoo)

So at the first try, the file system didn't find my class file as it is case sensitive.

However once I used the class static property, the autoloader which is not case sensitive was able to find my class, loaded by the previous call !