# Inheritance: can't find parent

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have been breaking my head on this one for a few hours and I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work. I have two php classes

```
<?php
class Mother
{
    public function __construct()
    { }
}
```

And the child class.

```
<?php
require_once('Mother.php');
class Child extends Mother
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

These classes are in seperate files and I have simplified them drasticaly for this example.

According to what I know and What I found in several other questions on SO this should work fine. But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mother' not found in *route to child class* on line 4

Any solutions or ideas where I should keep looking?

EDIT: both files are in the same folder

EDIT: added a debug before the class declaration
The file is called 4 times and 3 times out of those the Mother class is present
yet one time it is not which throws a fatal error(even though by the time I am using the child class the Mother class is present)

EDIT: right now I have just removed the extend and placed inherited functions in the child class so I can keep working. I will be posting the solution when I find it.

Comment: Have you included the file accordingly? Is the child class file in the same folder as `Mother`? Please share how you are using them, and also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475931/problem-with-php-includes-on-case-sensitive-file-systems)

Comment: Please show us your directory structure( path to mother and path to child)

Comment: Both files are in the same folder.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are creating a new Child?

Comment: You should look up how to use *composer's autoloader*.

Comment: @ka_lin thanks for the link casing does not seem to be the issue here

Comment: @tereško I'm not using composer in this project so that's not an option I'm afraid

Comment: You should *start* using Composer. Essentially every PHP project these days starts with it. It's the standard.

Comment: It must be something with the require not working as expected I think. Has anyone experienced trouble with this before?

Comment: How do you include the Child class?

Comment: with a require_once in the same way that the child class does with the mother class. But that works fine else I would be getting a fatal error saying that the child class cannot be found.

Comment: never user relative addresses with php they are a nightmare as they don't work the way you are expecting the `__DIR__` variable is your best friend

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but your 
require_once('Mother.php');
 is not including your mother class.  Make sure they are in the same folder or add path to require_once.

Comment: the path is correct(I double checked just to be sure). I just drastically simplified the code to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your `require_once` statement

you are using a relative address which seems like the right thing to do but is in fact relative to the file that the server has contacted not the child class

so assuming
root/index.php

```
Require_once "Child.php"
```

and assuming
root/classes/Child.php

```
Require_once "Parent.php"
```

in this case it will look for the parent in the `root` folder not the `classes` folder

you have 2 options 1 use the `__DIR__` variable

ie

```
Require_once __DIR__ . "/Parent.php"
```

this will force the require to use the folder the file is in, not the folder the original call is in

another option is to use an autoloader
which would look like this

```
<?php
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
        $fname = __DIR__ . '/classes/' . $class . '.php';
        if(file_exists($fname))
        {
            include_once($fname);
        }
    })

?>
```

this will then instruct php to look for any unknown classes in the classes foldder and load them into the system

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but as I mentioned this code has been simplified a lot. the normal require looks more like this require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '*directories*/mother.php'); Sorry for the confusion but I can't just go putting our actual code online

Comment: well sounds like you have over simplified the code, try writing a demo site that duplicates the error you are having then you can give us actual code that we can see whats going on